# Insert image in a general setting laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use the following code to put the general settings of Laravel, but these are all text. What should I do to put a photo?

```
 $footertext=Settingsite::get_value('footertext');
        $footertext2=Settingsite::get_value('footertext2');
        $footertext3=Settingsite::get_value('footertext3');

        return View('admin.site_setting',[
            'footertext'=>$footertext,
            'footertext2'=>$footertext2,
            'footertext3'=>$footertext3,
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably this photo is uploaded somewhere, it can be on your server or some external server. So all you need is the path to that photo and in your view, just use the  tag. For example:

```php
return view('admin.site_setting',[
               'photo' => $photoPath
           ]);
```

And then in your template file, you will just use the photo variable, like this:

```html
<img src={{ photo }}/>
```